# Given a graph, test if some vertices are more connected than the background

Tags: graph-theory, bioinformatics, networks, igraph

I have a neighborhood graph of some 10k vertices (a k-NN graph of single-cell RNA-seq data).

I am interested if a given set of vertices is more connected to each other than you would expect by chance. In particular I am looking for

- a score that describes how connected the vertices are and
- a statistical test that tells me if the vertices are more connected than a randomly chosen set of vertices.

The score should be comparable between different sets of vertices, s.t. I can conclude the vertices in set "A" are more connected than those in set "B".

**EDIT**

I though about

- as a score: dividing the number of edges in the subgraph by the number of *possible* edges in the subgraph, i.e.
  $S = \frac{|E|}{\frac{|V|(|V|-1)}{2}}$
- For the test: generating a background distribution by randomly sampling sets with the same number of vertices from the graph

But I have the feeling there must be a more standardized metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for, I think, is the now classical [graph modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks)). It is usually computed on an entire graph partition, but it may as well be computed for only a specific part.

You may also find inspiration from the various graph partition quality functions used in the literature; I suggest you have a look at:
[A Generalized and Adaptive Method for Community Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2518) by
Romain Campigotto, Patricia Conde Céspedes, and Jean-Loup Guillaume.

Comment: To connect the concept of modularity a bit more closely to OP's question, it's good to point out that it is based on a null model with fixed degrees. I.e., it shows how much more connected a group of vertices is than it would be in a random graph with the same degree sequence.  Other null models are possible too.